# iOS: can I programmatically decide what component to interact with (scrolling)?

Tags: ios, scroll, gesture, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm in a situation where I have two scrollable views, one horinzontally and the other vertically. Is there a way to detect if the user did a vertical or horizontal gesture, and depending on that, choose the view to interact with?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you wish to do something with the scroll depending on the direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` from `UIScrollViewDelegate` to get the direction on which your scroll will go.

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let translation = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView.superview)
    if translation.y > 0 {
        // swipes from top to bottom of screen -> down
    } else {
        // swipes from bottom to top of screen -> up
    }
}
```

But since this method doesn't return a scroll view, you will only know which scroll was dragged and to which direction.

Answer (score 1):

Please see if **isDirectionalLockEnabled** helps.
This helps to lock the scrolling direction.

> If this property is YES and the user begins dragging in one general direction (horizontally or vertically), the scroll view disables scrolling in the other direction. If the drag direction is diagonal, then scrolling will not be locked and the user can drag in any direction until the drag completes.